# How do you create small devices that can remain "dead" for a very long time without damaging the battery?

Tags: sensor, low-power, battery-operated, lipo

I'm working on a product that uses a very small 20mAh lipo battery. The device only needs to operate for 8 hours, and that's not a problem. However, I expect that customers may run the device until it shuts down, and then toss it in a drawer for 6 months. At the end of that 6 months I want the device to be able to recharge and work normally. The way I'm approaching it now, that seems very difficult to achieve.

Lets say I'm conservative and shutdown the device while 10mAh are still left in the battery. 6 months is 4368 hours. So the maximum current draw to not overdischarge the battery in that time is **2.29uA**.

I have a MCU plus several sensors and voltage regulators. Even with everything in shutdown mode it doesn't get that low.

Current approaches I'm aware of:

- I could buy new parts specifically looking for low quiescent current. For some of the sensors such parts are not available. As a result I'd have to create external shutdown circuits, which adds cost and complexity.
- Use some type of circuit that cuts power to everything (high side mosfet?). Are there ICs for this?

How do you guys approach this problem? Are there other strategies I'm missing?

Comment: Well, you could add an off switch.

Comment: 2.29uA sounds reasonably doable with a low-power MCU, which often are designed to be able to be powered directly off a lithium cell. Then, use a MOSFET or similar device to disconnect the sensor supply while the MCU is off – that adds indeed complexity, but limited to a whole of 1 to 2 components. I'd argue that's OK.

Comment: `2.29 μA` *including* self-discharge. Difficult even at non-elevated temperatures (glove compartment).

Comment: Have you considered the self-discharge rate of the battery on its own?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, but afik the self discharge of lipos decreases a lot as the voltage gets lower. I was under the impression that it virtually stops around 3.6V.

Comment: I only asked if you'd considered it @Drew <-- if you have then no problemo.

Comment: @Drew I'd like to see what you saw, regarding self-discharge for lipo. I have read that Eneloop batteries may lose only 20% of capacity in 2 years' time. I've had very good experiences with Eneloop (what I have are more than a decade old, now) but also never actually tried to make measurements on them. Other brands never fared anywhere near as well. I can say that much. So I'd suspect that self-discharge might depend highly upon your battery's manufacturer and methods. Given your needs, you may want to select one of very good quality and not assume they are all alike in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

2.29uA sounds reasonably doable with a low-power MCU, which often are designed to be able to be powered directly off a lithium cell.

Classical candidates in this field are TI MSP430 series microcontrollers. An ultra-low-cost (as in: 30 ct @1000pcs) MSP430FR2100 can run in a standby mode that preserves RAM state at less than 1 µA. That leaves another 1 µA available for leakage. (There's also ARM Cortex-M0+ microcontrollers that achieve 1 µA with full SRAM retention, but typically, they will eat more power when they're *not* in standby. Really depends on your use case.)

Then, use a MOSFET or similar device to disconnect the sensor supply while the MCU is off – that adds indeed complexity, but limited to a whole of 1 to 2 components. I'd argue that's OK.

If you have a device that you power from some supply IC, make sure that supply IC has a shutdown pin (and a sufficiently low-power shutdown mode!), or also feed it only through the MOSFET mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, that sounds doable... but what is the point? The MCU is still doing nothing useful. Might as well shut it down too. I am in favor of using the latter OP option and have global power switch that will simply disconnect the battery below certain voltage. No code necessary to support sleep or control that FET

Comment: And BTW, many of those power management ICs have support for power button debouncing, long/short press handling and an input for MCU-initiated shutdown, which simplifies schematics and reduces parts count even more. They are available in tiny BGA packages too.

Comment: Ah, true! Let me clean up my comments then.